# How to Create a Virtual Machine on Android that Acts Identical to a New Phone?

Tags: samsung, rom-flashing, custom-roms

I'm trying to create a vm/second OS on my phone because I need to install a program that can only be installed when booting up a phone after a factory reset. However, all of the vms I've tried open with an already functioning phone. Are there any that act identically to a new phone, even requiring you to sign in with a google account when you first open it?

Comment: What app are you talking about? I am not aware of a functionality that could restrict app installation to an installation directly after factory reset.

Comment: @Robert It's a phone lockdown software, maas360 to be specific, with two ways of installation, either by just installing the app from the app store and giving it admin privileges, or by installing it from the beginning stages of booting up after a wipe. I'd like to be able to test it the second way, without the need to wipe my phone or get a different phone to test it on if possible

Comment: A wipe deletes everything all data and all apps, so the an installation of an an app directly after boot is to my knowledge not possible on common devices. So you need the app to be installed as system app, included into the firmware which only works on a custom ROM or if you are the manufacturer of the phone.

Comment: @Robert I've messed around with it some and, while I'm not sure how it works, this is how it's installed. https://www.securitylearningacademy.com/mod/book/view.php?id=13794&chapterid=659 Somehow in entering the code afw#maas360 instead of an email it can configure in Device Owner mode. I need to test that mode, but can only install that mode if, upon virtual phone creation is takes me to connect a google account.